# How to put value of JSON into TableView

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I am a beginner on IOS application developement and I want to add the value of all keys of a JSON file into a tableView.

I have tried the code below but the tableView is still empty.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

var arraylist = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let session = URLSession.shared
    let url = URL(string: "http://country.io/names.json")!

    let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in

        do {
            if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? [String: String] {
                 for (key, value) in json {
                    let someString = value
                    self.arraylist.append(someString)
                 }
            }
        } catch {
            print("JSON error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return(arraylist.count)
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    cell.textLabel?.text = arraylist[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Comment: check if the delegate methods are getting called or not.

Comment: Yes, it work's good - I can see the code of UITableViewDelegate

Comment: Do you know anything about Decodable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First of all check if

  - `datasource` and `delegate` of the table view are connected to the view controller in Interface Builder.
  - the identifier of the prototype cell is set to `cell`.
- Add an `IBOutlet` for the table view and connect it in Interface Builder

  ```
  @IBOutlet weak var tableView : UITableView!
  ```
- Give the data source array a more meaningful and less euphemistic name

  ```
  var countries = [String]()
  ```
- After populating the datasource array reload the table view on the main thread

  ```
  if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? [String: String] {
      // easier way to get the country names
      self.countries = json.values.sorted()
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
         self.tableView.reloadData()
      }
  }
  ```
- Always `dequeue` cells

  ```
  public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
  {
      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
      cell.textLabel?.text = countries[indexPath.row]
      return cell
  }
  ```

And `return` is not a function (no parentheses)

```
return countries.count
```

Answer (score 0):

Reload your tableView with the new Data after getting it.
Also. if you haven't already, make your view controller/ view to be the delegate of the tableView.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

self.tableView.delegate = self
self.tableView.dataSource = self

let session = URLSession.shared
let url = URL(string: "http://country.io/names.json")!

let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in

    do {
        if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? [String: String] {
             for (key, value) in json {
                let someString = value
                self.arraylist.append(someString)
             }
             self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    } catch {
        print("JSON error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
task.resume()
```

}

Comment: when i try you solution, i got these errors :   self.tableView.delegate = self -> -> Ambiguous reference to member 'tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)'          
        self.tableView.dataSource = self -> Ambiguous reference to member 'tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)'

Comment: Where did you setup your tableView? If in Interface builder, check the outlet of your tableView and its delegate/datasource outlets. it should be connected to File's Owner. assuming this code is written in a ViewController

Answer (score 0):

Just add self.tableView.reloadData() at the end of you do block, so it would be

```
do {
   if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? [String: String] {
      for (key, value) in json {
      let someString = value
      self.arraylist.append(someString)
      self.tableView.reloadData()
   }
}
} catch {
   print("JSON error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

Comment: not work also i have self.tableView.reloadData() -> Ambiguous reference to member 'tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)'

Comment: would that get called before you have completed fetching the data, maybe try moving it to the end of your fetch to see